# Firebase prefer separate collections over mixed collection?

Tags: database-design, nosql

I'm writing an education app and my current Firebase structure looks like:

```
Course
   ∟ Lesson
       ∟ Modules (Includes video, audio, text and quiz modules in one collection)
```

Where "Course", "Lessons" and "Modules" are each collections. I also have a type field inside the module document that tells me what I should deserialize the document to (video object, audio object, etc. -- the objects only differ by a few fields).

Something tells me that I should instead separate the types of modules into their own collections however:

```
Course
   ∟ Lesson
        ⊢ Video Modules
        ⊢ Audio Modules
        ⊢ Text Modules
        ∟ Quiz Modules
```

I've thought a lot about the two options and I can't seem to decide. Is there anything about not mixing the types inside collections specific to Firebase or noSQL databases that would help me decide?

Comment: Nobody can Tell you. We need to know more about how the modules relate to the lessons. Does order matter?

Comment: Hi, no order does not matter although I do have an index field on the module documents that I use to order them in the UI. The lesson is a one to many relationship with modules. I think I've got an answer for myself (although it may not be the best one) so I'll post that below. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using one `Module` collection inside a `Lesson` that holds everything including videos, audio, text and quiz modules instead of multiple `Collections` inside a lesson.

This meant I didn't have to build a nest of streams for each collection, which looked unmanageable when I tried to implement it.

I now just have a `Module` interface that handles deserializing the document into the correct object (e.g. AudioModule) and in my UI, I use some `if else`s to check the type of the object to display the correct page.